# Destafffed but we like you

Tags: termination, freelance

My boss called me today to tell me the project I am working on is being destaffed.

For me, it's good news, somehow.

Last month, there were changes about this project (change of BU and managers etc.).

When my boss announced the termination, he insisted on the fact that "we like you and we are satisfied with your work, and we will try to find a new position for you, we do have new opportunities, we just don't have a visibility".

By the way, I am a freelancer.

Is this a nice good bye speech (start job hunt?) or should I trust them and wait?

**Update:**

A colleague of mine who knows more about the freelance culture said they were very generous with me when they gave me 4 weeks notice.

The common practice is that the termination announcement is made without any notice for freelances.

Comment: **"Is this a nice good bye speech (start job hunt?) or should I trust them and wait?"** - They neither promised you a new job nor terminated you outright. If it were me I'd probably start looking for other opportunities in case nothing materializes.

Comment: Could you please clarify - "For me, it's good news, somehow." - do you mean "I'm happy to hear that, and ok if they possibly call me back, but for now I'll enjoy my life" OR "How on earth they think it is good news to me, I'm so unhappy now"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I meant I am happy because the project is becoming confusing and I've been thinking about leaving but managers would tell me they want me stay. I can finally look for a better opportunity now.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere one month.

Comment: "change of BU". What is "BU" in this context?

Comment: @DaveGremlin It means business unit. The project lost customers or failed to get intended customers maybe, and now it has been parked (no need to cancel it for the time being). That's my interpretation.

Answer (score 18):

If this were me I would immediately start looking for a new job.  The statement made by your manager won't buy groceries.  If they find a spot for you then you will have that option.  But protect your own interests first!

Answer (score 10):

> *we just don't have a visibility*

You need to read between the lines - this is a polite way of saying we don't know whether you'll be able to continue, please search for alternatives already.

Especially, being a freelancer, when they come up with a role suitable for you, it's easier for your to accept (as compared against a full time employee) - just don't keep on waiting for it.

Answer (score 4):

When you get laid off, it’s nice to know that it is because the company has no money, and not because you were incompetent, lazy or otherwise not suitable.

Giving four weeks notice is nice of them; as a contractor there is zero notice required. Use it to find a new position.

On the positive side, there is a small chance that you get a job offer from this company in the future, since they know you, know that you did a good job, and offer you a job without going through an expensive agency.

Comment: I spoke to the customer monday morning, he sounded annoyed and kept saying "you know" a lot. He said they don't want freelancers anymore.
He asked me if it was ok for me to change my contract so that he could recommend me.
In the meantime, I spread out my resume, and my boss called me monday afternoon (side effect?) and asked me to update my resume for a staffing in another project.
An assistant contacted me as well to update resume and send it to her.
I am not sure if they really have something for me or they are just manoeuvering?

Answer (score 2):

Never trust anything that isn't in writing. Then don't trust what's in writing until you get paid. This isn't about trust, it's about moving to your next opportunity. If they want to retain your services, they need to expedite and provide you an offer in writing as soon as possible. Until then, you should be looking for your next gig and ready to move along when you find something suitable.

Comment: And also consider what type of paper it is written on…

Comment: Even when it is written in paper, the ink could be "**disappearing ink**", which is a kind of "**magic**" ink that automatically disappears after 24 hours or so.... :-)

Comment: Also consider "we will try to find you a job" written on a piece of paper is rather meaningless. It is no guarantee at all that they will indeed find you a job, only that they will make some token effort to do so.